# How do you set the thickness of the horizontal gridlines in the WPF toolkit datagrid control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpftoolkit, wpfdatagrid

I am using the WPF toolkit datagrid to display some data and want to increase the thickness of the horizontal girdlines for each row, I would have thought this would be a simple thing to do but i can't find solution.

Comment: I agree!  i want the same thing. It seems to be impossible with WPF.  I can easily create borders around my cells or rows. But that is not the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never done this, but I would try to set the `BorderThickness` of the rows via the `RowStyle` property. Here is some documentation about the [RowStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowstyle%28VS.95%29.aspx) and for the [DataGridRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridrow_members%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

Hope this works. A short follow up with the result would be great.

Regards

**EDIT**

As you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness_members.aspx), you can set only e.g. the bottom property. So only the vertical bottom lines should appear.

```
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0, 0, 0, 5"/>
```

Comment: I don't want a border around each row, i don't want vertical gridlines just horizontal ones.